# Angular 2 *ngIf condition body still rendering when condition is false

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a loop in an Angular 2 template that is giving me an error because my service, `_adfService`, is apparently null (even though it logs as non-null prior to any error.) Just to try to get it working, I wrapped it in an `if` statement to see if I could prevent the loop from rendering whenever `_adfService` happens to be null. I still get the same error:

```
Cannot read property 'grids' of undefined
```

Why can't I prevent the loop from causing an error if Angular 2 is supposedly not rendering the body of the condition?

```
    <span *ngIf="_adfService != null">
      <li *ngFor="let grid of _adfService.grids" router-active>
        <a class="navlink" [routerLink]="['group/1/grid/']">Grid 1</a>
      </li>
    </span>
```

Comment: The error can't come from the code you posted. It probably comes from some code in your component.

Comment: Did you forget a parameter property annotation in your constructor like `constructor(readonly _adfService: AdfService)`?

Comment: Try *ngIf="_adfService !== null" or just *ngIf="_adfService"  if also won't work, problem exist somewhere else.

Comment: @ulou it's clearly `undefined` there's no reason to do that. Also `*ngIf="_adfService"` is better style and will check for all of these and be correct unless the service could validly have the value `0` or `NaN` which wouldn't make any sense. Stop using `null` damn it!

Comment: Figured it out. I assumed the error was coming from my component, but it was coming from within my service where I was reading 'grid' from an undefined object in a getter. Derp.

Comment: ... And Angular wasn't doing a good job of telling me where the error was originating from.

Comment: @BBaysinger honestly, while I have many major issues and complaints with Angular 2, it really could not do better here. The error was in your service and I am glad that Angular 2 keeps its shamefully dirty hands out of my services as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're evaluating for null in the *ngIf, which is a totally different value than undefined in Javascript/TypeScript.

To fix it, just change the *ngIf to this:

```
<span *ngIf="_adfService">
```

That will evaluate if the _adfService variable evaluatues to "true" (that is, is not undefined, not null, not false, not zero, and not an empty string) and thus not render the *ngFor if the variable is not initialized with the object you're trying to use.